# How do I set equally-spaced xtickmarks using a specified list of floats that are not uniformly spaced?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a heatplot and want to label the equally-spaced x-axis tickmarks using values from a list. The list values are floats, given in increasing order, but not uniformly spaced.

Here's what I've tried for a heatmap corresponding to a 5-by-20 matrix using a list of four tickmark labels: [1.2,2.3,4.7,8.3]:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M=np.random.rand(5,20)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
pos=ax.imshow(M,aspect='auto',cmap='jet')
fig.colorbar(pos, ax=ax)

labels=[1.2, 2.3, 4.7,8.3]
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(len(labels)))

ax.set_xticklabels([t for t in labels])  
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph has four equally-spaced tickmarks on the horizontal axis. The first three are labelled, from left to right, as 2.3, 4.7, and 8.3. The last tickmark has no value, and the first value of 1.2 does not appear in the lower-left corner as desired. I can't seem to determine how to correct this.

[image]

Comment: Try turning the list of labels to strings, and use pcolormesh(labels, y, M). That will make the x axis a categorical axis rather than a numerical one.

Comment: I have not used pcolormesh before, but I'll look into it. It would seem a bit strange if I couldn't  do it with imshow though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `imshow` doesn't take an x and y argument, so it can't use a categorical x axis.

Comment: I'm also unclear why you have 20 values in x and only 4 labels.  Are the 4 labels for every 5th data bin in x?  Which data bin do the labels align with, the first one, the 3rd?

Comment: Yes, essentially the four labels are for every fifth data bin. 
Larger context:  I have a 5-by-1000 matrix corresponding to 5 sensors and 1000 time points. Chosen at random are 4 non-overlapping subwindows of time length 100 each. Suppose the starting indices of the subwindows are 60, 280, 410, and 756. Then my heat map will be for the 5-by-400 matrix, and I want labels of '60', '280', '410', '756' to appear at x-axis coordinates 0, 100, 200, and 300.

Comment: @fishbacp Wasn't sure if the `60 280 410 756` labels should be created dynamically somehow. I hard-coded them into my answer below, but if there's a formula you're using I'll be happy to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `set_xticks` is what you're missing. The positions can be created equidistant by just using `range` and setting the step size:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_cols = 20
M = np.random.rand(5, num_cols)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
pos=ax.imshow(M, aspect='auto',cmap='jet')
fig.colorbar(pos, ax=ax)

labels = [1.2, 2.3, 4.7, 8.3]
pos = range(0, num_cols, num_cols // len(labels))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(len(labels)))
ax.set_xticks(pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: output1]

Per your comment above, for a 5-by-400 matrix, you'd just change the following:

```
num_cols = 400
labels = [60, 280, 410, 756]
```

which produces:

[image: output2]